# How to load data from a CSV-file to a Highcharts sankey diagram

Tags: csv, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I want to load data from an external CSV-file to a Highcharts sankey diagram. After trying several options, I am not sure if this is even possible, as the result is always an empty chart? The CSV-file will be on the same server in the final version.

As a simple case, see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oy095kzb/
which is merely copy/paste from the [official Highcharts sankey example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sankey-diagram) (where data is included in the code), except that data-module is loaded and csvURL is used instead:

```
series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: {
            csvURL:'https://www.test.basleratlas.ch/sankey_test.csv'
        },
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
}]
```

CSV-file-structure:

```
'from', 'to', 'weight'
'Brazil', 'Portugal', 5
'Brazil', 'France', 1
'Brazil', 'Spain', 1
'Brazil', 'England', 1
'Canada', 'Portugal', 1
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the `data.csvURL` feature is using to fetch the data from the CSV which is stored on the server, like this link: https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/vs-load.csv, meanwhile it seems that your link downloading the CSV file. Next notice that your CSV file doesn't have defined column names.

---

EDIT

Notice that the data object should be defined outside the series object config.

Also, I used the complete callback to parse the data into the proper format.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qLu37548/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

Comment: Thank you. Added a header row and file is shown in browser now, but still no chart content showing up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @Sebastian. Rearranging the columns using `data.complete` was the missing part.